# caret in mvprintw but only in loop

Tags: c++, string, terminal, char, ncurses

I have the following program

```cpp
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();
    const char c = static_cast<char>(65);
    mvprintw(0, 0, "%s", &c);
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

it prints simple "A" and waits.

[image]

If I modifying "x" argument of `mvprintw`

```
        mvprintw(0, 1, "%s", &c);
```

it will print "A" with empty space prepend on beginning.

[image]

If I will add `for` loop starting from `0` it also works as expected

```
int main() {
    initscr();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        const char c = static_cast<char>(65);
        mvprintw(0, i, "%s", &c);
    }
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

will show the same result as in first example.

But if this loop starts from `1` there is stragne `^A` at the end.

This code:

```
int main() {
    initscr();
    for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
        const char c = static_cast<char>(65);
        mvprintw(0, i, "%s", &c);
    }
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

produces

[image]

and I even do not know how to debug it?

Comment: @john, can you add this as answer? It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mvprintw` is anything like `printf` then you are supposed to provide a nul terminated string when you use `%s`. Try this instead

```
const char c[] = { static_cast<char>(65), '\0' }; 
mvprintw(0, i, "%s", c);
```

Note in this version `c` not `&c`.